# How to split 64-bit integer into 2 32-bit integers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript, and I just learned that 64-bit integers are instead floating type, so when I want to put a very large integer on the screen, it is off by a few (depending on the precision at that magnitude).

I want to do some arithmetic with very large numbers, and the precision is not sufficient.

Rather than move to string-based math, I just want to split a 64-bit integer into two 32-bit integers so that I can have full precision.

If it helps, most of the math I will be doing is bitwise.

Something along these lines would be perfect:

```js
let numAsString = "123456789012345678" // very large number
// turns into
let upperHalf = getUpperHalf(numAsString) // 123456786224119808
let lowerHalf = getLowerHalf(numAsString) // 2788225870
/*
do math with upperHalf and lowerHalf
*/
```

So how am I supposed to write a function to get the upper half and bottom half of this very large number if there is not sufficient precision to hold all of the bits necessary? I believe 53 bits is the maximum.

**Edit based on a comment:** I know JavaScript is not the preferred language for this task, but the program is very simple and short. I've already written the program in other languages; my point in asking is how would this be done in native JavaScript. At the moment, I'm learning about the way programming languages work and what it means for them to handle things differently from each other.

Comment: [...BigInts are a thing...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: If your application is numerically intensive, perhaps Javascript is not the right choice.  There are very good Python libraries for math.

Comment: @TimRoberts I know, I have already written the program in Python. I'm just wondering how would I go about doing this in JavaScript natively.

Comment: My suggestion would be to break it to operate using the decimal number system.  Split the long number sting into two small strings and then use parseInt to create the two smaller number, do your math on these smaller numbers and then concatenate them back together.

Comment: @SGandhi No. Just use `BigInt`!

Comment: Are you asking how to do the calculation (answer: use `BigInt`) or are you still asking how to split a 64 bit integer into two 32 bit integers (it's not necessary for the calculations)?

Answer (score 0):

Your `123456786224119808` isn't the upper half but rather difference between the number and its lower half.

Use bitwise operators:

```js
const num = BigInt("123456789012345678");
const shift = BigInt(32);

const upper = num >> shift;
const lower = upper << shift ^ num;

console.log(Number(lower), Number(upper));
```

To get the lower you could use `asUintN` (the same speed in chrome as bitwise operators):

```js
const num = BigInt("123456789012345678");
console.log(Number(BigInt.asUintN(32, num)));
```